# Panels from jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to get the swipe function at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.php#demo-page without formatting all the forms and other things which are included in jquery mobile? I am justing looking for the panels?

Comment: So you only want to have panel and swipe functions without the rest of jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Yes. Do you know any repository with only these functions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some jQuery plugins you can try: http://jpanelmenu.com/index.html or http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/